# Автоматическое обновление контента

Tags: ajax, php, javascript

Есть аукцион. Необходимо сделать, так, чтобы при следующей ставки любого пользователя, никнейм автоматически обновлялся без перезагрузки страницы. Ник берется из базы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого есть WebSockets:

> WebSocket — протокол полнодуплексной связи поверх TCP-соединения, предназначенный для обмена сообщениями между браузером и веб-сервером в режиме реального времени.

http://habrahabr.ru/post/82140/

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать функцию для обновления определенного блока на странице, например:

```
function nikRefresh()  
{  
    jQuery.ajax({  
        url: "page.php",
        type : 'post',
        success: function(html){  
            jQuery("#content").html(jQuery('.data', data).html());
        }  
    });  
}
```

где  `url: "page.php"` - это страница, которая будет обрабатывать запрос, а  `jQuery("#content").html(jQuery('.data', data).html());` - это то, что мы будем заменять (в данном случае блок с `id="content"` на блок с `class="data"`).

Функцию можно запускать при изменении ставки.

**Обновление**

Ну ставка куда-то же записывается, добавляется в массив, например, проверять на новые элементы можно, на изменение размера или при изменении значения самой ставки. Если пользователь меняет ставку по клику, можно ловить событие клика по этой кнопке.

**Обновление 2**

Можно, конечно сделать автоматическое обновление блока на странице постоянным с интервалом, только это будут постоянные запросы на сервер с проверкой изменилось ли значение (если да - то заменить блок, нет - ничего не делать), честно, не знаю, как с этим будет справляться сервер.

Comment: Каким образом она узнает, что ставка изменилась?

Comment: @e13, мне нужно не изменение для конкретного пользователя, а для всех, кто находиться сейчас на данной странице.

Comment: @e13, да это то понятно, не лучшее решение. Я думал, может какую технологию подскажет, менее затратную по отношению к серверу

Answer (score 1):

Такого рода методы обновления называются Comet. Самые популярные:

1. AJAX Polling - клиент периодически дергает сервер с запросом на изменения. Минус тут очевиден - при большом числе пользователей, очень резко вырастет число запросов на BackEnd;
2. WebSockets - клиент и сервер общаются в двустороннем режиме. Все бы хорошо, если у вас все пользователи использует IE >= 10 версии и не сидят на ваших сайтах через прокси (т.к. прокси просто не позволит выполнить HTTP-запрос Upgrade);
3. AJAX Long Polling - в данном методе общения сервер может слать уведомления в клиент. На этой технологии построены чаты VK, Facebook-а и т.д. Суть заключается в том, что сервер не закрывает соединение с клиентом. Получается BackEnd всегда может что-то дописывать в результат, а клиент их уже видеть. Для этого метода есть хороший модуль к Nginx-у https://github.com/slact/nginx_http_push_module

P.S. Если вы пишете на NodeJS, то вам может подойти такая вот либа - http://socket.io/. По дефолту она юзает веб-сокеты. Если они браузером не поддерживаются, то там уже fallback идет вплоть до Flash-а.

Answer (score 0):

Для аукционов WebSocket самое то.

AJAX и рядом не стоит, большие преимущества по скорости - один произвел изменения - тут же инфа рассылается по нужным клиентам, и при этом клиенты не нагружают сервер запросами.

Это самая наименее затратная технология для сервера.